# Save downloaded images in one PDF in R

Tags: r, image, pdf, join, download

I'm downloading a  few .pngs of a website, saving them in a separate folder and now I'm trying to join them in a single pdf, each image on a different page.

Everything I've found uses a different language but I would love to do everything using R, is it possible?

Comment: *"Is it possible?"*.  This is not a programming question.  It is a Y/N question.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
#-- Load libraries
library(png)
library(grid)

#-- Parameters
nFiles <- 2
file_name <- "test"

#-- Open pdf
pdf(file = "test.pdf")

#-- Read the files & plot
for (i in 1:nFiles)
{
    img <- readPNG(paste(file_name, i, ".png", sep = ""))
    grid.raster(img)

    if (i < nFiles) plot.new()
}
#-- Close pdf
dev.off()
```